# Sonar coverage after upgrade of spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, sonarqube

I have upgraded one of my spring boot projects to [2.7.5](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.7.5) version and after analysis of projet on sonarqube server I got a 0% coverage, even I have already lot of unit tests.

Any idea of what is causing this ?

I have tried to reanalyse my project using mvn sonar:sonar but in vain

Comment: No experience, but maybe a higher JUnit version was installed, no longer recognizing the older one.

Comment: In fact after various tests, it is related to JUnit tests that are ignored because of the upgrade of spring boot version which upgraded all testing frameworks used in my projects @JoopEggen